# How to add record and auto sort sequential file in java?

Tags: java, file, addition, record, sequential

```
public void addTrainRecords(TrainData t){

    OpenFile();

    TrainData current = null;
    current = readRecord();

    while(current != null){

        current = readRecord();
    }
    writeRecord(t);



    //closeFile();
}
```

I need to add record and auto sort record data in order
now I add record to file sequentially but not sort yet.
my record is an object of TrainData which has order number

example
      
 I add train number 3

 then add train number 1

I want it to sort to 1 then 3 while add the record to the file

Anyone know how to do it?, please help

 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store all your records in a `List<TrainData>`, sort the list using [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), then iterate through the list and write each record to the file.

Or read each record as you're doing now. At each iteration, if the new record has not been written yet, compare the current record to the new one and, if bigger than the new record, write the new record, then write the current record. At the end of the loop, if the new record has not been written yet, write it.

```
TrainData current = null;
boolean newRecordWritten = false;
for (current = readRecord(); current != null; current = readRecord()) {
    if (!newRecordWritten && firstBiggerThanSecond(current, t)) {
        writeRecord(t);
        newRecordWritten = true;
    }
    writeRecord(current);
}

if (!newRecordWritten) {
    writeRecord(t);
}
```